# Mathematics mod with ln

Tags: math-mode, mathematics

I don't get it how to use here mm mode to get these

[image]

`$\ln{\dfrac{\sum_{n,m=u_{k}}}{2}}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```latex
\[\ln\left( \frac{\sum\limits_{n,m =\mu_k} \tilde\alpha_k^{n,m} \cdot 
\tilde\beta_{k+1}^{n,m} \cdot \delta_k^{n,m} }{\sum\limits_{n,m=00} 
\tilde\alpha_k^{n,m} \cdot \tilde\beta_{k+1}^{n,m} \cdot \delta_k^{n,m}} \right)\]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it :D

Comment: You can check the answer as approved if it suited your needs :)

Comment: Also take a look at the wikibook https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics It has good information on how to typeset equations.

Comment: Remember that upvoting is different than accepting the answer. [Here is more info](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) if you need it.

Comment: :D Thank you, I hope now I accept it